# Append search query to iframe src URL

Tags: jquery, url, search, iframe, append

I have a form on my home page for visitors to search for their postcode. When the submit button is clicked the home page redirects to another internal page that has an iframe. I want the search query string appended to the iframe src URL.

e.g. A search for postcode 3000 will append "?postcode=3000" to the iframe src URL

```
<iframe src="https://www.externalwebsite.com?postcode=3000" class="auto-height" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

This is the code I'm using for the search on the home page:

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue) this.value='';" onblur="if(this.value=='') this.value='Submit Postcode...';" value="Submit Postcode..." id="postcodesearchQuery" maxlength="4"/>
<input name="searchbutton" value="" type="button" onClick="location.href='postcode.aspx?postcode=' + $('#postcodesearchQuery').attr('value')" id="postcodesearchbutton" />
```

This of course adds the search result to the URL of the "postcode.aspx" page.
e.g. `www.mywebsite.com/postcode.aspx?postcode=3000`

Is it possible to use jQuery append to add the `?postcode=' + $('#postcodesearchQuery').attr('value')` to the iframe URL src?

*EDIT*

If I add the following to my head tag, it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $('.myiframe' + iFrameID).attr('src', url);
    url += '?postcode=' + postcodeValue;

    function setIFrameSrc(iFrameID, postcodeValue)
{
    var myFrame = $('.myiframe' + iFrameID);
    var url = $(myFrame).attr('src') + '?postcode=' + postcodeValue;
    $(myFrame).attr('src', url);

}
</script>
```

iframe code:

```
 <iframe src="www.externalwebsite.com" class="myiframe" width="100%" height="750px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set it with jQuery, using the attr function:

```
$('#' + iFrameID).attr('src', url);
```

Of course you must set the url first, like this:

```
url += '?postcode=' + postcodeValue;
```

Putting these into a function we get:

```
function setIFrameSrc(iFrameID, postcodeValue)
{
    var myFrame = $('#' + iFrameID);
    var url = $(myFrame).attr('src') + '?postcode=' + postcodeValue;
    $(myFrame).attr('src', url);

}
```

Comment: Do I add this to the page with the iframe? Also do I need to declare the id of the iframe? Is that what the # is for?

Comment: Yes, the '#' is for the id, if you have more iframes which should have this functionality then you should rather use jquery class instead of id in the selector. But with this solution you need an id for the iframe, the javascript function should be pasted into a script tag in the page or into a js file which should be used by the page. Then you should call this function where appropriate with correct parameters and it should work.

Comment: I've made an edit to my original post, can you tell me what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You may not need jquery, like this:

```
window.frames["postcodesearchQuery"].href += ?postcode=' + ...
```